# Pressing multiple keys simultaneously

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

how can i send a string/messagebox when multiple keys have been pressed at the same time?
Ive tried both `And` aswell as `Andalso`, but the result is that only the first key is needed to pop up that msgbox.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, _
                                       ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) _
                                       As Boolean
        If msg.WParam.ToInt32() = CInt(Keys.ShiftKey) AndAlso CInt(Keys.A) Then
            MsgBox("Testing")
            Return True
        End If

        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: AndAlso CInt(Keys.A) has no (real) meaning as far as it is always true (CInt(Keys.A) exists always). You have to look for the WParam associated to the combination ShiftKey+A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, _
                                   ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) _
                                   As Boolean
    If keyData = (Keys.Shift Or Keys.A) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Shift-A")
        Return True
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Note that this

Comment: yes, this works. But i dont understand how could "Or" work in this condition. Doesnt "or" mean that if any of the keys are pressed, the condition becomes true?

Comment: No.  In this case "Or" is performing a **bitwise operation** on two numeric values (the key codes for Shift and A).  See [Bitwise Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a(v=vs.90).aspx).